# SQL Server 2008 CPU Troubleshooting on 6 identical servers

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance

We offer an API service that rotates between 6 identical SQL Servers on a "round robin" rotation. I'm trying to troubleshoot some high CPU usage on one of the 6 servers but have hit a wall.

All of the servers use the exact same Stored Proc query plans and are rotated evenly. One server ("Server 1") is hitting around 80% CPU whereas the rest are sitting at around 40% CPU. 3 of the servers are waiting on 96 major windows updates and the other 3 are waiting on 30. The server in question is one of the servers waiting on 96 windows updates.

However, a few weeks ago one of the servers that was waiting on 30 windows updates had the same problem. This server was again sitting at around 80% CPU and the rest at 40%. It's as if the high CPU usage is shifted between servers at random.

I've run multiple traces on Server 1 and it appears to behave in the exact same way as the other servers. Reindexing and Update Stats are run at the same time on every server and produce the same query plan each time across all servers. I'm running out of ideas on where to look, can anyone possibly point me in the right directly?

Comment: I'd start by using PMON (Process-->% ProcessorTime-->_Total and sqlservr instances)to see how much SQL Server is contributing to overall CPU. That will suggest next steps.

Comment: @DanGuzman Processor time is almost 100% for SQL Server according to PerfMon